# Am I not updating my React state correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I hope you can help, I've reduced my
code to make it more concise.

**Objective:** I'm trying to create a callback that removes the first item from the `playOrder` array every 2000 milliseconds until there are no more items left in the array.

**Problem:** Each time `playOrderHandler` runs, the `playOrder` duplicate assigned is always 4 items even though the `useEffect` callback is showing that the new `playOrder` array has been set as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is much appreciated

```
    const [chamberSpinning, setChamberSpinning] = useState(false)

    const [playOrder, setPlayOrder] = useState(
        [
            'left',
            'right',
            'left',
            'stop'
        ]
    )

    useEffect(() => {
        if (chamberSpinning) {
            console.log(playOrder, playOrder.length) // logs 3 items
        }
    }, [playOrder])

    function chamberSpinInit () {
        setChamberSpinning(true)
        playOrderHandler()
    }

    function playOrderHandler () {
        if (playOrder.length > 0) {
            const playOrderDup = [...playOrder]
            console.log(playOrderDup) // Logs 4 items every time
            playOrderDup.splice(0,1)
            setPlayOrder(playOrderDup)
            spinIt()
        } else {
            console.log('No more plays remaining')
        }
    }

    function spinIt () {
        setTimeout(() => {
            playOrderHandler()
        }, 2000)
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={() => chamberSpinInit()} >
            SPIN THE CHAMBER!
        </button>
    )
```

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks all,

Moe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *plain* recursive call of `spinIt` is problematic because the `spinIt` in scope at the time of that call is the same `spinIt` that was defined at the time of rendering earlier - it's not the new `spinIt` that gets created as a result of calling `setPlayOrder(playOrderDup)` (and the subsequent rerender). Put the recursive call in a `useEffect` instead, which will close over the proper current value of state.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const App = () => {
    const [chamberSpinning, setChamberSpinning] = useState(false);
    const [playOrder, setPlayOrder] = useState(
        [
            'left',
            'right',
            'left',
            'stop'
        ]
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        if (chamberSpinning) {
            console.log(playOrder, playOrder.length);
            spinIt();
        }
    }, [playOrder, chamberSpinning])

    function chamberSpinInit() {
        setChamberSpinning(true)
        playOrderHandler()
    }

    function playOrderHandler() {
        if (playOrder.length > 0) {
            setPlayOrder(playOrder.slice(0, -1));
        } else {
            console.log('No more plays remaining')
            setChamberSpinning(false)
        }
    }

    function spinIt() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            playOrderHandler()
        }, 2000)
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={chamberSpinInit} >
            SPIN THE CHAMBER!
        </button>
    )
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```